# Python Djangoの開発の中で Scheduleライブラリを利用すると、ローカルホストが立ち上がらない

Tags: python, python3, django

python,djangoを利用したWEBシステムの中で、スクレイピングで情報を定期的に集める処理を行うため、scheduleライブラリの利用を試していますが、ローカルホストを立ち上げるために、
`python3 manage.py runserver` を実行すると下記のエラーが出てしまいます。

解決の方法について、ご存知の方おりましたら、ご教授いただけないでしょうか？

```
2020-01-09 19:49:26,345 [INFO]  /Users/myapple/python/djangoproject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py(Line:584)   Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...
```

試験的に公式ドキュメントに近い内容のコードにしていますが、上記のエラーが出てしまいます。

```
import time
import schedule as schedule

def test():
    print('I am working')

schedule.every().day.at("10:00").do(test)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

---

**追記**

下記のように、while True:以下3行をコメントアウトすると、サーバーが立ち上がります。

```
import time
import schedule as schedule

def test():
    print('I am working')

schedule.every().day.at("10:00").do(test)

# while True:
    # schedule.run_pending()
    # time.sleep(1)
```

実行環境
Python: 3.7.5
Django: 2.2.2
schedule:0.6.0

Comment: `[INFO]`はエラーじゃないですよね...「`StatReloader`でファイルの変更を監視します」ってことです。※`StatReloader`は、ソースコードを変更するたびにDjangoが開発サーバーを自動リロードするために使用するクラスのようです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
なるほど、エラーではないのですね。
ただ、ローカルサーバーは立ち上がらず、サイトの表示等を確認できないのですが、通常どおりに立ち上げる方法はあるのでしょうか？

Comment: 最初の質問時に記入していなかったのですが、[INFO]メッセージの後に、Performing system checks...と表示されています。（質問欄にも追記しました）

Comment: 最初の質問に追記しましたが、# while True:
    # schedule.run_pending()
    # time.sleep(1)というように、コメントアウトするとサーバーは立ち上がります。

Comment: Djangoの起動処理に無限ループを組み込んでしまって、起動が完了しないんでしょうね。

Comment: 何らかの定期タスク実行のライブラリーを使ってみてはどうでしょう？django-celeryというライブラリーがあるみたいです。[日本語の記事](https://qiita.com/shinno21/items/8c57a66536c0f38b3fbb)がありました。もっといいのがあるかもしれませんが。

Comment: 貴重な情報ありがとうございます。djangoのフレームワークが関係しているのですね。紹介していただいたライブラリーで組み直してみようと思います。